# Can a pywebview window be kept always on top?

Tags: python, pywebview

When using the Python package `pywebview`, is it possible to create a window and keep it on top, like an always-showing control panel in the corner?

The application will mostly be run on Windows, so if there isn't a platform independent solution, I am also curious if a Windows-specific solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is currently not implemented in the released version, but one possible implementation is currently being considered for inclusion in the project.

See the [issue](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/issues/476) where the feature was requested, as well as the [pull request](https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/pull/478) for the potential implementation.

Comment: I have just realised that this is YOUR issue/pull request.